# Can one trust gentile sources for trope systems?

Tags: gentiles, trop-cantillation, trust-neemanut

Learning the trope systems for specific Sephardic or Mizrahi communities isn't the most easy since many of the melodies have mixed in together (creating something like the Yerushalmi), or just a lack of knowledgeable teachers. However, there were instances when gentile Europeans traveled to the middle east to chronicle and notate the chanting systems of these communities, writing them down into sheet music with various descriptions. Can these sources be trusted and used for learning particular nusachim for trope?

The specific instance in question was documented for Egyptian Cantillation, it was documented by french musicologist Guillaume André Villoteau in the years 1798 to 1800, but his work wasn't published until 1826.

You can see the work [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=JUv0AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA473&dq=de%20l%27etat%20actuel%20de%20l%27art%20musical%20en%20egypte%20473&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAGoVChMIsq2-_6r8xgIVFjGICh2N3wrC#v=onepage&q=de%20l%27etat%20actuel%20de%20l%27art%20musical%20en%20egypte%20473&f=false), which is written in french, with mixes of Hebrew characters, and sheet music.

Another example might be the treatise of Wickes regarding the grammatical nature of the te'amim.

Comment: well unless one can find some halachic impropriety in using inaccurate cantillation, then there isnt any danger in using it.

Comment: @mevaqesh If the inaccurate cantillation results in improperly parsing the sentence, that could be a halachic impropriety.

Comment: Similar: Johann Reuchlin, a German Hebraist, documented the form of the German trop, which is nearly identical to what was in use as recently as the 1930s (and in declining use in the post-war period).

Comment: Sounds like they're *meisichin l'fi tuman* which works to *mattir* an *eishet ish* so why should here be any worse...?

Comment: @Loewian Can you translate that into English please? :)